# looping through an array in stored procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, loops, merge

Scenario :

I need to return a single result set from a stored procedure, however I have an array parameter which can pass unknown multiple values, and for each value that is passed I need to have a seperate logic of getting data.

SP :

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecommendations]
(
  @RecommendationTypesCSV  varchar(4000) -- This could have Type1,Type2,Type3...
}

BEGIN
....
END
```

Once I convert this comma seperated types, I need to go through each types and perform some logic, however as I keep on performing the required logic, I gather data and finally I have to do a Union All and return all the results as one big resultset with a new column of type with its relevant type information assigned to it.

```
If (type1)
BEGIN 
-- Do Something
END

If (type2)
BEGIN 
-- Do Something
END

If (type3)
BEGIN 
-- Do Something
END
```

Merge all three and return result :

```
Column1     Column2     Column3
----------- ----------- -------
102570      10027       type1
102569      20011       type1
102568      20011       type1
102564      20011       type2
102563      20011       type2
102562      20074       type3
102561      20011       type3
102560      20011       type3
102559      10059       type3
102558      20011       type3
```

Problem :

I need to make a decision as to whether I should make a single call to the DB (SQL) or multiple calls per type and then merge the types into code (C# .Net), please keep this in mind that this is a WCF client facing service and performance is a huge decision making factor, and also that the types are not limited to just 3 types and could be more types.

If its efficient to make a single DB call is cursor the only possible way to loop through the types and merge them - examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the code to hand, but an efficient way I've used in the past does involve passing through a CSV, and then populating that into a temporary table which can be used with JOIN statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some legacy systems that use this technique. It looks a bit like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecommendations] 
    ( @RecommendationTypesCSV NVARCHAR(4000) ) 
AS  
BEGIN
   DECLARE @StartPos INT  
   DECLARE @EndPos INT  

   -- split recommendation types list into table  
   DECLARE @RecommendationTypes (  
       [Type] NVARCHAR(40)
   )  
   WHILE LEN(@RecommendationTypesCSV) > 0  
   BEGIN   
       SET @StartPos = 1  
       SET @EndPos = CHARINDEX(',', @RecommendationTypesCSV) - 1   
       IF @EndPos <= 0 SET @EndPos = LEN(@RecommendationTypesCSV)  

       INSERT INTO @RecommendationTypes VALUES (SUBSTRING(@RecommendationTypesCSV, @StartPos, @EndPos))  
       SET @RecommendationTypesCSV = SUBSTRING(@RecommendationTypesCSV, @EndPos + 2, LEN(@RecommendationTypesCSV))   
   END  

   If EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @RecommendationTypes WHERE [Type] = 'type1')
   BEGIN 
       -- Do Something
   END

   ...

END
GO
```

But generally I prefer using [table valued parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) where possible.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[RecommendationTypes] AS TABLE 
    ( Type VARCHAR(40) );
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecommendations] 
    ( @RecommendationTypesCSV [dbo].[RecommendationTypes] READONLY ) 
AS  
BEGIN

   If EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @RecommendationTypes WHERE [Type] = 'type1')
   BEGIN 
       -- Do Something
   END

   ...

END
GO
```

The only problem is that it's more difficult to call the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @RecommendationTypesCSV [dbo].[RecommendationTypes];
INSERT @RecommendationTypesCSV VALUES ( 'type1' ), ( 'type2' );
EXEC [dbo].[GetRecommendations] @RecommendationTypesCSV
```